# Javascript: replace inside a replace

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

My input is many lines of text that looks like this:

```
a.b.c.d.e (f:g)
```

I need to turn this into

```
a.b.c.d.e (a/b/c/d/e/f?g)
```

Note that the dotted part (`a.b.c.d.e`) can have varying numbers of elements, so sometimes it'll be `q.r.s.t`, sometimes `u.v.w.x.y.z` and so on. I have a `replace()` that will give me `(a.b.c.d.e.f?g)`, but what I need is then to turn all those `.`s into `/`s in the result.

Is there a way to do a replace inside a replace? Or should I just call replace() on the string twice?

Sorry if this question is poorly worded, I'm not awfully well versed at regular expressions in javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very crazy way of doing it:

```
var str = "a.b.c.d.e (f:g)";
var re = /([^\s]+)\s\(([^:]+):([^\)]+)\)/;
var newStr = str.replace(re, function(a,b,c,d){ return b + " (" + b.replace(/\./g,"/") + "/" + c + "?" + d + ")"; });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6wZJa/)

Comment: replace() can take a function as its second parameter? that is so cool it hurts

Answer (score 3):

You need to chain the calls to `replace()` one after the other.

```
var result = source.replace("foo", "bar").replace("oof", "rab");
```

Answer (score 1):

A saner way :) http://jsfiddle.net/smfPU/

```
input = "a.b.c.d.e.w.x.y.z (f:g:h)";
output = input.replace(/:/g, "?");
outputparts = output.split("(");
left = outputparts[0];
middle = left.replace(/\./g, "/").trim();
right = outputparts[1];
output = left + "(" + middle + "/" + right;
document.write(output);
```